# Turning off the KendoUI Scheduler k-current-view button

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using **Kendo UI v2016.2.714** and **jQuery v1.9.1**.   I am unable to turn off the scheduler tool bar k-current-view which seems to redundantly indicate which of the Day/Week/Month buttons is selected: 
[image]

This appears to be the result of a recent KendoUI upgrade as I never saw it before.  Basically I just want to see the three buttons which I have defined in my javascript file:

```
 var sch = $("#schAppointment").kendoScheduler({
            date: new Date(), // date: new Date(), The current date of the scheduler
            showWorkHours: true,
            workDayStart: new Date("2013/1/1 06:00 AM"),
            workDayEnd: new Date("2013/1/1 08:00 PM"),
            height: 700,

            timezone: "Etc/UTC",
            views: [{
                type: "day",
                eventTemplate: $("#event-day-template").html(),
                eventHeight: 40
            }, {
                type: "week",
                eventTemplate: $("#event-week-template").html(),
                eventHeight: 40
            }, {
                type: "month",
                selected: true,
                startTime: new Date("2013/1/1 06:00 AM"),
                endTime: new Date("2013/1/1 08:00 PM"),
                eventTemplate: $("#event-month-template").html(),
            }],
```

I have not found in the Kendo documentation how to disable this k-current-view and I am still learning Javascript so I haven't discovered how to find the attribute to disable either.

Answer (score 0):

Just for those who might be looking for this answer:

Turns out it was the missing kendo.*.min.css type files.  I upgraded everything else but that...dumb mistake